# Is it necessary to explicitly restore a control font when its parent window is destroyed?

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc

I use the following code in my windows create method

```
HANDLE hFont = ::GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT);
m_InfoTab.SendMessage(WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFont);
```

m_InfoTab is a standard Windows/MFC tab control. Is it necessary to save the original font and restore it when the parent window is destroyed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not required to restore the original font. You are however responsible for managing the font object yourself, i.e. deleting it when it is no longer used. The documentation for [`WM_SETFONT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632642.aspx) is fairly explicit here:

> The application should call the DeleteObject function to delete the font when it is no longer needed; for example, after it destroys the control.

In this particular case you will not run into any problems since you retrieved the font object through a call to [`GetStockObject()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144925.aspx). These objects are controlled by the system and it is not required to call DeleteObject on them (although it is not harmful either).

Whether or not your application leaks GDI handles can easily be verified using Task Manager. Go to the *Processes* tab, select *View* -> *Select Columns...* and tick *GDI Objects*. With the monitoring in place change your code and install a timer using [`SetTimer()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644906.aspx) with `uElapsed = 1000` (once a second). Add an `OnTimer` handler with the following code:

```
void CMyDialog::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent)
{
    // Retrieve the system font
    HFONT hFontSystem = (HFONT)GetStockObject( DEFAULT_GUI_FONT );
    LOGFONT lfSystem = { 0 };
    GetObject( hFontSystem, sizeof( lfSystem ), &lfSystem );
    // And construct and identical font object
    HFONT hFontNew = CreateFontIndirect( &lfSystem );
    // This will leak the font object
    m_InfoTab.SendMessage( WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)hFontNew );

    __super::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
}
```

Now open Task Manager, start the application and watch the GDI Objects count increase by 1 each second.

Answer (score -1):

No, the window in question (m_infoTab) is responsible for managing its fonts, and freeing the old one if necessary.

Comment: -1 Since a window cannot safely deduce _"if [it is] necessary"_ to free the old font object it cannot possibly manage font objects. The application has to control the life time of font objects.

Comment: You misunderstood my response. If you set a new font in a window (call it X), it is **that** window (X) that is responsible for freeing its own font if it needs freeing. You are making a distinction between "application" and "window" where one does not exist.

Comment: I didn't misunderstand. The window cannot deduce whether the font is under its sole control or not. Font objects aren't ref counted and even if they were the ref count could **temporarily** drop to 0 until the application decides to reuse the font object for another control. In short, `WM_SETFONT` does not transfer ownership, hence the font object remains under control of the application.

Comment: Sigh. I guess I did not explain myself well enough. Ok, say in the `WM_CREATE` handler for a window, you call `CreateFont` to create a font to use for that window. Someone then comes along and sends you a `WM_SETFONT` message. Who deletes the old font?

Comment: You are imposing restrictions on the original question that aren't there. Of course there is nothing wrong with properly structuring your application. But stating that a stock MFC control automatically manages the fonts it was handed through `WM_SETFONT` is misleading at best.

Comment: The original question was specifically about the standard tab control, and specifically as to whether the OP had to delete the font that he got back when changing the font. I said no, he didn't. By all means feel free to explain the concept in more detail in your answer but my answer was not inaccurate.